# What is the next number in the sequence below?

Tags: number-sequence

> 11 31 51 44 64

Possible answers are:

1. 74
2. 59
3. 93
4. 67

Comment: I think this question is a little unfitting for this community, in terms of its difficulty.

Comment: You may want to review [Number Sequence Puzzles: What (Not) To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do), since this question seems to match the "what not to do" in that post.

Comment: I hate it when new users get such an unfriendly welcome, but what else can we do? Please, OP, don't be annoyed, rather, carry on your adventure on this site!

Answer (score 3):

It's

> 93

Because

> sum of the digits of each number is 2 more than the sum of the digits of the number before that.

Comment: Huh, that's such a poorly defined "pattern"...